# Need help using apply @@ and @@@ functions with Grad

Tags: function-construction, format

I need help using `Apply` (`@@`).

In the following code

```
f[x_, y_] := x^3 - y*Cos[Pi*(x/y - y)] 
coord = {{3, 5}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}}
f @@@ coord

Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}]

Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}] @@@ coord
```

I am getting a `Apply` function across the list but is not doing the actual calculation over the list.  Why is the `Grad` function not working when applied to `coord`?

Comment: Check out this link: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice or get the Elementary Introduction to the Wolfram Language book

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason your last line is not working is because `Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}]` is *not* a function, but a list of (operations applied to) symbols.

What you need is instead a function taking two inputs and giving two outputs.
One way to do this is by explicitly defining one

```
(* define function *)
gradf[x_, y_] := Evaluate[Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}]]
(* apply function to coord *)
gradf @@@ coord

(* {{27 - Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8] \[Pi], 
  1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]) + 28/5 Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8] \[Pi]}, {48 + (
   Sqrt[3] \[Pi])/2, 
  1/2 - (10 \[Pi])/Sqrt[3]}, {27 - Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8] \[Pi], 
  1/4 (1 - Sqrt[5]) + 28/5 Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8] \[Pi]}} *)
```

If you want to stick in using a shortcut notation, not defining an extra function, you can use

```
Function[{x, y}, Evaluate@Grad[f[x, y], {x, y}]] @@@ coord
```

Note that the use of `Evaluate` is necessary here, otherwise the function would replace the values of the elements of `coord` also in the derivation variables `{x, y}`.